# Finding 10 characters before a character

Tags: c#

How can I find 10 characters before a character in string? For example;

```
string abcd = "asdsdasdasdasdasdasasdasasdssXsdasdsadas";
```

How can I find 10 characters before X ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 string result=string.Empty;
 string abcd = "asdsdasdasdasdasdasasdasasdssXsdasdsadas";

    int indexOfStringToSearch = abcd.IndexOf("X");
    if(indexOfStringToSearch!=-1)
      { 
        if(indexOfStringToSearch -10 >0)
            result = abcd.Substring(indexOfStringToSearch-10,10);
        else
            result = abcd.Substring(0,indexOfStringToSearch-1);
     }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
string searchWithinThis = "asdsdasdasdasdasdasasdasasdssXsdasdsadas";
string searchForThis = "X";

int firstCharacter = searchWithinThis.IndexOf(searchForThis);

if (firstCharacter < 0) {
  Console.WriteLine("Character {0} not found", searchForThis);
} else {
  Console.WriteLine("First occurrence: {0}", firstCharacter);
}
```

If you want the 10 characters before X, including X:

```
int tenCharactersBefore = Math.Max(firstCharacter - 10, 0);

string result = searchWithinThis.SubString(tenCharactersBefore, 10)
Console.WriteLine("The ten characters before are {0}", result);
```

If you want the string of 10 characters before X, not including X:

```
int tenCharactersBefore = Math.Max(firstCharacter - 11, 0);

string result = searchWithinThis.SubString(tenCharactersBefore, 10)
Console.WriteLine("The ten characters before are {0}", result);
```

If you want just the character that is 10 characters before X:

```
int tenCharactersBefore = Math.Max(firstCharacter - 10, 0);

string result = searchWithinThis.SubString(tenCharactersBefore, 1)
Console.WriteLine("The ten characters before are {0}", result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`String.Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx) and [`String.IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof.aspx) methods like;

```
string abcd = "asdsdasdasdasdasdasasdasasdssXsdasdsadas";
Console.WriteLine(abcd.Substring(abcd.IndexOf("X") - 10, 10));
```

*Basicly*, you get the index of `X` and subtract `10` with that position, after that, you get the substring starting that position and getting `10` character after it.

Of course, you should check first if `X`'s index is larger than `10` or not. Because if it is smaller than 10, you should check;

```
if(abcd.IndexOf("X") < 10)
    Console.WriteLine(abcd.Substring(0, abcd.IndexOf("X")));
else
    Console.WriteLine(abcd.Substring(abcd.IndexOf("X") - 10, 10));
```

Output will be;

```
asdasasdss
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/wYMX3J).

Answer (score 0):

If there will only be one 'X' character:

try this:

```
string abcd = "asdsdasdasdasdasdasasdasasdssXsdasdsadas";
string[] words = s.Split('X');
Console.WriteLine(words[0].substring(words[0].length-10,10));
```

or for multiple

```
string abcd = "asdsdasdasdasdasdasasdasasdssXsdasdsadas";
string[] words = s.Split('X');
for(int i=0;i<words.length; i++)
{
   Console.WriteLine(word[i].substring(word[i].length-10,10));
}
```