# How Can Get Characters Between 2 Character?

Tags: c#

How can i get characters between two character ? Example ;

```
string example = "aaaaaaaaXbbbbXaaaaaa";
```

How can  get `bbbb`?

Comment: Use `Substring` and `indexOf`

Comment: Isn't this sufficiently similar to [your other recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16752338/finding-10-characters-before-a-character)? Note that in both cases, I think you have failed to tell us how far you have come when trying yourself.

Comment: Do you want to get a precise substring or just a chars limited by  other precise ones, there s some difference out there !

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`String.IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof.aspx) and [`String.LastIndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.lastindexof.aspx) methods of `String` class for getting the positions of `X`'s in your string, after that you can use [`String.SubString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx) method for based their positions.

```
string example = "aaaaaaaaXbbbbXaaaaaa";
int firstXposition = example.IndexOf("X");
int LastXposition = example.LastIndexOf("X");
Console.WriteLine(example.Substring(firstXposition + 1, LastXposition - firstXposition -1));
```

Output will be;

```
bbbb
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/TzmL5n).

Comment: Just code without any explanation may serve for mindless copy-and-pasting, but is unlikely to help any future readers who have similar problems.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Enough now?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Good to hear `:)`

Answer (score 2):

You may try like this 
where substring holds two parameter 
first the starting point of the string after escaping the `no of characters i.e 9`
second is no of characters need to `display i.e 4`

```
string example = "aaaaaaaaXbbbbXaaaaaa";

    string sub = input.Substring(9, 4);
    Console.WriteLine("Substring: {0}", sub);
```

Comment: Just code without any explanation may serve for mindless copy-and-pasting, but is unlikely to help any future readers who have similar problems.

Comment: explained..and thanks for the note:)

Answer (score 0):

```
string s = "aaaaaaaaXbbbbXaaaaaa";
string[] words = s.Split('X');
```

now you can use the foreach loop to get whatever you want.